# "Permission denied" with embending JW Player in my PHP with signature (python sample)

Tags: php, jwplayer

I get "Permission denied" with the following code:

```
$api_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$time_expires = time() + (60 * 100);

$mmmmd = md5(utf8_encode("players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.html:{$time_expires}:{$api_secret}"));
// alternative tests that did not work:
// $mmmmd = md5(utf8_encode("players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.js:{$time_expires}:{$api_secret}"));
// $mmmmd = md5("players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.js:{$time_expires}:{$api_secret}");
// $mmmmd = md5("players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.html:{$time_expires}:{$api_secret}");

$theurl = "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.html?sig={$mmmmd}&exp={$time_expires}";
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo "{$theurl}"; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" title="somename" style="position:absolute;" allowfullscreen>
```

yyyyyyyy and vvvvvvv are taken from the code that you can create from within the dashboard.
yyyyyyyy=media_id
vvvvvvv=player_id

here is the sample code in python:
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/protect-your-content-with-signed-urls#section-signature

The JWPlayer support team can't really help, they believe that their python sample is enough to understand which is the right "Path"

Can anybody help please?

Comment: How can anybody help, you haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say "Permission denied". It was really late. :P

Comment: What do you mean by "permission denied"? That's not part of your code after all

Comment: One way or the other thaks for reading my question. BUT "I get Permission denied with the following code" means that you have to put the code in a php file and actually test the code to get the "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

Below is my suggestion after reading the docs and your code. Changed the syntax around. Also, changed the cdn to https.

Cannot test though, sorry, I only have a company acc and we don't do these cloud hosted ones right now.

```
<?php
$api_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$exp = time() + (60 * 100);
$to_be_md5d = 'players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.html:' . $exp . ':' . $api_secret;
$sig = md5($to_be_md5d);
$theurl = 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/players/yyyyyyyy-vvvvvvv.html?exp=' . $exp . '&sig=' . $sig;
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $theurl; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" title="somename" style="position:absolute;" allowfullscreen>
```

Another try based on your comment, and what they wrote as an example function:

```
$media_id = "yyyyyyyy";
$player_id = "vvvvvvv";
$api_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$exp = time() + (60 * 100);
$path = 'players/'.$media_id.'-'.$player_id.'.html';
$sig = $path . ':' . $exp . ':' . $api_secret;
$sig = md5($sig);
$signed_url = 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/'.$path.'?exp='.$exp.'&sig='.$sig;
```

And about what they said that you need a Video signature, THEN a player signature... or something:

```
$media_id = "yyyyyyyy";
$player_id = "vvvvvvv";
$api_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$exp = time() + (60 * 100);
$path1 = 'videos/'.$media_id.'.mp4';
$path2 = 'players/'.$media_id.'-'.$player_id.'.html';
$sig = $path1 . ':' . $exp . ':' . $api_secret;
$sig = md5($sig);
$signed_url = 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/'.$path2.'?exp='.$exp.'&sig='.$sig;
```

Comment: At some point the "support" team answer the following which was not supporting me at all and I am trying to use another way of protecting my videos :  
If you would like to create a Manual Embed, then you would need both a link to the Player and jwplayer().config() object to manually create your player.

    If you follow the manual approach, you will need to alter the demo code available for creating a Signed URL.
        You would alter the code first to produce only a Video Signature
        And then alter the code to produce a Player signature.

Comment: Tried following the logic of their example code in the edit... but I guess it's kinda the same as the first one? :D What happens when you open the url in the browser though? Oh wait, I had another idea!

Comment: Honestly..... I am REALLY disappointed from their support and I only test your code because you tried to help me. If you read the hole response email with an explanation image and everything and realize that they made so much effort to explain , when they could do half the effort and pass you a simple example of the code, as I asked them.........   NO, I will close this question JWPlayer is not worth it.